# Strange behaviour on Win7 embedded machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7

Our application (C# .Net 3.5) works fine on WinXP machines (embedded or not). Now we move to Win7 embedded machine.

If we put our application under C:\, no problem.

If we put our application under "C:\Program Files" directly, we cannot launch it. Windows will popup a "... Stopped working" window.

if we first put our application under C:\, launch it, when copy it to "C:\Program Files", it will launch fine.

We don't have write activities which will create or modify files located under "C:\Program Files". All our new files and modified files are located just under "C:\MyFolder".

We don't have an installer yet. What we deploy our application is copy and paste.

Any idea about this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried running it as administrator? That will at least tell you if it is a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, the account we logon is administrator.

Comment: That isn't what @Kevin asked. Have you tried right-clicking the exe and choosing Run As Administrator? If you have no errors when you do that, you will gain really important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't guess at this problem.  Write an event handler for the AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException event.  Display or log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Probably tied to UAC regardless of any apparent IO activity. Does the program make use of any dll files in its folder?