# VS2010 application doesn't run on another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, win32gui

I created a Win32 application (WinForm) is VS2010.

When I click the application icon in the Debug (or Release) directory, the form is shown and the project runs normally (on Windows 7).

When I move this "icon" to another computer, and click it, it doesn't run, and I get an error message of Windows **"Send Error Report / Don't Send" ...** (I tried on windows XP and 7)

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you copied the entire application - the .exe and all the dependent dlls?

Comment: Yes' I copied all "debug" directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour on Win7 embedded machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700773/strange-behaviour-on-win7-embedded-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Your program is throwing an exception.
You can add `catch` blocks to show the exception details and find out what's wrong.

You're probably missing a DLL file.

Comment: I don't find any dll file in the project directory